# How do I patch/update foreign key with OData.Delta?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata

Trying to make use of System.Web.Http.OData.Delta to implement PATCH methods in ASP.NET Web API services, but it seems unable to apply changes to foreign key relation properties.

consider this data type, which it should be possible to update in a PATCH request to the Web API service:

```
public class Company
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    // [Required]
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int ? CountryID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CountryID")]
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }

}
```

Every thing works fine when I update name/ description properties.However, when i try to update the country Id property,I can see following request originating from browser.

```
CountryID: 3
Description: "e"
ID: 10
Name: "EF"
```

But at server side both country object and country id property is always null in `Delta<Company>`  object.

Any idea how to upate foreign keys using delta/patch?

Comment: Just found that OData Delta<t> only update properties that are basic types or classes. Inherited classes, nullables, generics, integer,derived types aren't supported yet. I have solved this problem using deserialization method available at: https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/DeltaJsonDeserialization/ReadMe.txt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just found that OData `Delta<t>` only update properties that are basic types or classes. Inherited classes, nullables, generics, integer,derived types aren't supported yet. (May be supported in future releases).

I have solved this problem using deserialization method from a sample available here:

[Link](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/latest#Samples/WebApi/DeltaJsonDeserialization/ReadMe.txt)

Comment: Do you have a reference for " Inherited classes, nullables, generics, integer,derived types aren't supported yet."?

Comment: I had the same problem with inherited members such as "IsEnabled" not updating by PATCH using OData where properties on the class would update. This was a great help and saved me a lot of time. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Having the same issue in 2021. Link is dead. Can you please provide a code or your solution? I guess the easiest thing is to somehow treat collections as normal props and simply replace them.